# nmap - single port scan returns result, range port scan returns all port in ignored state result

Tags: nmap

don't hate me, I am a newbie. If I do:

```
nmap -sV -p80 255.255.255.0
```

I get:

```
PORT   STATE    SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp filtered ssh
```

but if I do:

```
nmap -sV -p0-100 255.255.255.0
```

I get:

```
All 101 scanned ports on 10.129.189.143 are in ignored states.
Not shown: 101 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
```

How is that possible? The only difference I see is that I am scanning a specific port instead of a range, yet the results are different. All 101 ports are in the ignored state.

Answer (score 2):

The *results* aren't different, both outputs say port 22 is filtered, but one is just collapsing a long list of ports into an abbreviated form. It looks like it does this automatically when the list is longer than a certain length.